# There are four cabinets in total, right?

Tags: word-usage

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cabinet), "cabinet" is a countable noun, so I can say "a cabinet", "one cabinet", "two cabinets" etc.

[image]

In the image above, I guess each circle represents **one cabinet**, so do the arrows. So, there are four cabinets pointed out in total.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Assuming you're treating adjoining units of doors and shelves as a "cabinet" (although it's not clear where the line is actually drawn), there are at least 3 more cabinets in that picture.